# Python Community : Can we use BDD framework in community version?

Tags: pycharm, bdd, pytest-bdd

I am self learning automation testing using Python. When going through few blogs they mentioned they have used Pycharm Professional version for Behave or Py-test BDD framework.

Can we use Pycharm community version for BDD frameworks?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with PyCharm community version you can create PyTest-BDD framework. 
Only thing is you have to run via terminal or using pytest.main() to run the scripts

Ex : 
pytest.main(["-k", BDD_TAG, "--html="+LOACAL_REPORTS_FOLDER_PATH+"/Result/index.html"])

Comment: Thank you. Will try to execute as suggested

Answer (score 1):

Here is the matrix containing all the differences between Community and Professional versions: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html.

According to it BDD frameworks are supported only in Pro.